# Can google app scripts post an image (or file) to Google Cloud (not Drive) using an URL?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform

I want to use Google Cloud as a backup for my images which are currently in Rackspace cloud.  Each image has a URL.  I figured out how to write a google app script to do this successfully to Google Drive, but I want to do it with Google Cloud.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the size of the job Apps Script may have a quota bottleneck.

> https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas

Google Cloud Functions (similar to AWS lambda) may be a better tool.

> https://cloud.google.com/functions/

If you do think GAS would work check out a very well designed Apps Script library for Google Cloud Storage

> http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/googlecloud/gcsstore